# Why do these two "not in" queries have different results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are trying to weed out records that have a duplicate of certain columns. I built this query to show any row that has an 'N' for its Flag, if there is not a matching 'Y' record in the table with the same last/first name.

```
select * from Table where LName+FName not in
 (select LName+FName from Table where FLAG = 'y')
```

However this comes back with 0 results. The inner query does return expected results. If I run the inner query, and manually paste in the result values like below, it runs with results.

```
select * from Table where LName+Fname not in ('DoeJohn','AbelAdam')
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Can you try adding table aliases and see if the problem still exists , e.g `select a.* from Table a where a.LName+a.FName not in
 (select b.LName+b.FName from Table b where b.FLAG = 'y')` ?

Comment: No change in behavior with both tables aliased.

Comment: Any `null` names in either part of the query? Because `not in (list, including, null)` always returns indeterminate (and you should yield `null` for concatenated `null`s). The moral is: You should show a sample of data that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at your data... `NOT IN` fails when there is any `NULL` value. You can try either using `NOT EXISTS` or filtering any null values:

```
select * from Table where LName+FName not in
        (select LName+FName from Table where FLAG = 'y' AND LName+FName IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This appeared to be the issue. Some of the LName values were Nulls, I updated them to empty strings and the query runs as expected. Thank you!